# angular animations not working on ios

Tags: ios, angular

i'm using angular 6 cli, i have a transition i made which is not working properly on ios 8 and below. when i click the button the animation happens but it's not animating back to original state.
it works fine on all browsers and latest ios versions.

searched for hours but could not fix it, hope you could help me

here is the transition code

```
export const expandCollapse = trigger('expandCollapse', [
  state('collapsed', style({
    height: 0,
    paddingTop: 0,
    paddingBottom: 0,
    opacity: 0
  })),

  transition('collapsed => expanded', [
    animate('300ms ease-out', style({
      height: '*',
      paddingTop: '*',
      paddingBottom: '*'
      // padding: '*'
    })),
    animate('1s', style({ opacity: 1 }))
  ]),

  transition('expanded => collapsed', [
    animate('300ms ease-in')
  ])
]);
```

Comment: did you install pollyfills for animation?

Comment: yes, it works only half way, never goes back to original state on ios 8,7

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=animation check this it will not work on ios 8 and 7

Comment: i found a partial solution, it now works but not animation is not smooth, just added     {"transform":"translate3d(0, 0, 0)","offset":1}